# How to add a template in TextBox? WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I'm creating a custom TextBox with a Title and I'm trying do it with a template.
The problem is that I don't want to have a textbox inside of textbox.
For example:

```xml
<TextBox.Template>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <StackPanel Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="green">
      <TextBlock Text="Title"/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtBox}"/> <!-- How I can do it without this? -->
    </StackPanel>
  </ControlTemplate>
</TextBox.Template>
```

This way works like I want but I don't want to recreate the TextBox with binding.
Or is this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not putting "a textbox inside a textbox", you're putting it inside a *template*. Very different thing. There's still only one textbox, you're just extending its appearance.

If you want fundamental TextBox behavior then you have to use a TextBox in your template, there's not really any way around that. I suspect though that the real problem here isn't so much the TextBox as it is the explicit binding. If that's what you're trying to avoid then you can use a `TemplateBinding` to bind to the templated control's Text property instead:

```
<TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
```

EDIT: just as a follow-up to this, TemplateBinding is one-way only. If you need two-way binding then use `Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"` instead.